How to Deploy Containers in One GitHub Actions Runner and Run Tests in a Different Runner?
I am working on a CI/CD pipeline using GitHub Actions where I need to deploy my Docker containers in one runner and then run integration tests on those containers in a different runner. This setup is required because my tests need to run in a clean environment separate from the deployment environment.
What I Want to Achieve:
Deploy Docker containers in the first runner.
Wait until the services in the containers are fully ready.
Run integration tests in a different runner.

Main Concern:
Is it even possible to run containers in one GitHub Actions runner and then run tests against those containers in a different runner? My understanding is that once the setup job finishes, the runner might clean up the environment, which would stop the containers, thus making them unavailable for the test runner.
I tried setting up the workflow to deploy the Docker containers in one runner and then run the tests in another runner. Here’s what I did:
Deployed Docker containers in the first runner:
    Built and deployed the Docker images.
    Waited for the services to be ready.
    Captured the IP address of the Docker container.

Ran the tests in a different runner:
    Downloaded the IP address artifact.
    Set up Python 3.8 and installed all the required packages.
    Ran the test scripts.

However, I encountered the following issues:
The tests did not output anything and seemed to run forever.

I was expecting the tests to connect to the services running in the Docker containers and execute successfully.

Try using services to run your container under test. See here for details.
